# SSMTP and .forward

Tags: ubuntu, email, ssmtp, ubuntu-13.04

I configured the SSMTP in a ubuntu server 13.04.

Configured the root user email address.

Everything works correctly.

But, now I want to configure the "~/.forward" to send all emails to another address.

I created the file at the root user home /root/.forward, and added to it:

```
another@email.com
```

But this isn't working. When I sent a email to root, only the root email receives the email.

I'm sending emails with:

```
echo Msg body | mail -s Subject root
```

What I need to do to get the .forward file working?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I didn't think SSMTP support `.forwards`.  Did you see some document somewhere saying that it did?  If you really nead that, then you probably need a different MTA.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,  `ssmtp` does not read `~/.forward`. Here is a quote from the `ssmtp` manpage:

> It does not do aliasing, which must be done either in the user agent or on the mailhub.
>   Nor does it honor .forwards, which have to be done on the recieving host. It especially
>   does not deliver to pipelines.